# Chapter Heading Design

Tags: chapters

I'd like to design a chapter heading similar to the one in the picture below. I like to put a line between the number and the chapter name and also align the the chapter name to the left. I'm using the document class `book`. Any ideas how to do it?

[image]

Comment: By chapter name do you mean the word ‘chapter’ or the chapter title? The picture is aligned on the right. So?…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can build your own chapterstyle with the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\rmfamily}
  {\sffamily\flushright\fontsize{60}{0}\textbf{\textcolor{black!20}{{\Huge\chaptername}~\thechapter\vskip0pt\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}}}{0pt}
  {\flushleft\fontsize{30}{0}{#1}\vskip60pt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-40pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Enjoy the whitespace}

 \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The `type1cm` package is required for the font size.

[image]

Comment: `type1cm` is required if you use computermodern. If you use another font that exists in type1 or opentype format, you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bernard! Good one! Two questions: 1) Where in the codes I can play around with the spacing before after the line? 2) How can I add "CHAPTER" before one? With a smaller size ...

Comment: To change the spacing before the line you can simply change the value of `\vskip0pt\rule...` to any other value. If you want to change the space after you have to change the `...}}}{0pt}` at the end of the line

Comment: I have edited my answer for your second question.

Comment: Bernard, another question. How can I apply a separate font family to the title. I want just "Enjoy ..." part to be in normal latin font not ss.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer again. If you want the 'Chapter' and the number in serif font, simply delete the `\sffamily`-command before `\flushright`.